# Searching in results of querySelectorAll call

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a userscript, which extracts all links matching specified CSS selector, then performs several searches among child nodes of these links and then alter attributes of found elements. I'm looking for a way not to get all links matching first selector every time before searching, but only once. 
Example HTML:

```
<div>
<a class="some_class" href="http://some_href"><b>Link1</b></a>
<a class="another_class" href="http://another_href"><b>Link2</b></a>
<a class="some_class" href="http://www.some_href">Link3</a>
</div>
<span>
<a class="some_class" href="some_href"><b>Link4</b></a>
</span>
```

Javascript:

```
var links=document.querySelectorAll('a.some_class');
//some actions with the hrefs

//the following code could be a solution, but doesn't work as I need.
//it tries to get b elements from the extracted links with matching href 
//but generally this selector depends on some calculations with links

links.querySelectorAll('a[href$="some_href"] b')[0].style.display='none'; 
//NodeLists don't have this method

//another way: 
//trying to create document fragment from NodeList to call method on it  
var fragment=document.createDocumentFragment();
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
   fragment.appendChild(links[i]); 
   //Link is removed from page, so this also is not suitable
}
```

Of course, I can simply iterate through all chidlren of NodeList, but it is too slow if there are many links and many searches.

Comment: What exactly does *"a way not to get all links matching first selector every time before searching, but only once."* mean? You're trying to get all the elements *but not* the ones with that href ?

Comment: It's not really a solution because it's probably massively inefficient, but the correct way around the nodes being removed from the document is to simply clone them and append the clone only.  In any case that's kind of a really cool use of document fragments.

Comment: I'd suggest you describe the actual problem you're trying to solve (e.g. show us what you're actually looking for in the child nodes) so we can offer ideas on the best way to do this.

Comment: Also, you can use a selector like this too: `a.some_class[href$="some_href"] b`.  In which case if you aren't doing a whole lot of nesting, couldn't you just use `document.querySelectorAll` rather than selecting from the subset?

Comment: I'm probably stupid, but I've read this 20 times and can't for the life of me get what the expected result is? First you're getting all the anchors by class, then you're looking for anchors inside those anchors, and that doesn't work, but what exactly are you trying to do, what elements should be gotten and what elements shouldn't, and why ?

Comment: @adeneo @jfriend00 From the code snippet, it looks like OP wants to grab all links with a particular class, manipulate them a bit, then grab the `b` elements of some of those anchors filtered by `href`.  It's like when you use a framework like jQuery or mootools to get a bunch of stuff and then get a subset of that bunch of stuff.

Comment: @JosephMarikle selector `a.some_class[href$="some_href"] b` is not suitable, because `href` and types of child nodes depend on some calculations with links, that are made first. And there could be many different `href`s.

Comment: @Imieee so you're saying it's more flexible than always selecting `b` from the anchors.  It might be an entirely different element for a different set of anchors, correct?

Comment: @JosephMarikle Yes, it is more common task, but at least it would be good to solve it with links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about doing is *filtering* the list.

So first you get the list:

```
var links=document.querySelectorAll('a.some_class');
```

And then you want to filter it, for instance only finding the ones that also match `a[href$="some_href"] b` (but I understand that varies depending on the link in question).

I'd probably start by making the NodeList an array:

```
links = Array.prototype.slice.call(links, 0);
```

...so I could use the various nifty Array methods on it.

Then:

```
var bElementsUnderSomeHref = [];
var someOtherCriterion = [];
links.forEach(function(link) {
    var b;
    if (link.href.substr(-9) === "some_href") {
        b = link.querySelector("b");
        if (b) {
            bElementsUnderSomeHref.push(b);
        }
    }
    if (/*...some other criterion...*/) {
        someOtherCriterion.push(/*...something relevant...*/);
    }
});
```

There I'm doing a *single* loop, but if for any reason you needed to, you could use separate loops. A single loop saves you a bit of execution time, but it's not like this is slow. As [I demonstrated](http://jsbin.com/dunigude/1) the [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23560771/157247) you tried to ask this question, even IE8 can loop through (say) 20,000 elements and do nested `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll` calls on each of them in a quite brief time. For me, IE8 in an old XP VM does that in 320ms. Chrome does it in under 60.

Comment: It is quite obvious solution, but I will use your code if I don't find other solutions. And maybe you mean `Array.prototype.slice.call(links, 0)`?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I like your method of using the document fragment, but it could be amended slightly.  Namely you need to use node cloning with the deep option and utilizing prototype wouldn't be bad either.  Not sure how efficient it is, but it looks really frik'n pretty.

source: http://jsfiddle.net/FLXRx/
demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FLXRx/show/ (results displayed in console)

```
NodeList.prototype.querySelectorAll = function(selector){
    var fragment=document.createDocumentFragment();
    for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){
       fragment.appendChild(this[i].cloneNode(true));
    }
    return fragment.querySelectorAll(selector);
}

var links=document.querySelectorAll('a.some_class');
console.log(links.querySelectorAll('a[href$="some_href"] b'));
```

Comment: I also need to alter attributes of the found elements. Sorry, I forgot to mention it. Maybe it is possible to add each original node to cloned, but that would be even slower.

Comment: Well that would definitely render this method a lot less useful... In that case, one option would be to add an attribute to each node from the original list as a means of a unique ID... I'll have to give it some more thought